# Как расширить меню в две стороны?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как расширить меню в две стороны?

```
setTimeout(() => { document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "40%"; }, 2000);
```

если делать так то он расширяется только вправо

Answer (score 1):

начнем с того, что в нашей жизни счет и чтение идет слева направо, так же и пиксели на мониторе идут слева направо, поэтому у вас и идут расширение в правую сторону при изменение ширины. Приведу Вам два простых примера:

1. Мы создаем родительский `div` с `position: relative;` это для того чтобы дочерние элементы позиционировались относительно родительского элемента. После этого с помощью `postition: absolute` мы устанавливаем нужный нам блок в нужном положении с заданными параметрами `left` и `rigth`. С помощью данных параметров мы и изменяем ширину в нужные нам стороны.
2. Во втором примере же, мы используем расположение дочернего элемента по центу родительского. И при изменении ширины дочернего элемента, браузер будет автоматически ставить наш блок в цент и будет создаваться впечатление растягивания блока в обе стороны.

```js
setTimeout(() => { 
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0px"; 
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.right = "0px"; 
}, 2000);
```

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ffdddf;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="wrapper" id="mySidenav">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
setTimeout(() => { 
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "90%"; 
}, 2000);
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddffdd;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddccdd;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="wrapper" id="mySidenav">
    
  </div>
</div>
```